# EF Navigating across tables with .Include

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to extend this query..

```
        var itinerary = context.Itineraries
                .Include(i => i.ItineraryDays)
                .Include(i => i.ItineraryStartDates)
                .Where(i => i.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

.. to include 3 tables which are accessible through ItineraryDays using the following navigation properties to traverse.

- ItineraryDay>> public virtual Listing Listing { get; set;} (ItineraryDay.ListingId === Listing.Id)
- Listing>> public virtual Port Port { get; set; } (Listing.PortId === Port.Id)
- Port>> public virtual Country Country { get; set; } (Port.CountryId = Country.Id)

regards, Guy

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that case, you have to replace

```
.Include(i => i.ItineraryDays)
```

by

```
.Include(i => i.ItineraryDays.Listing.Port.Country)
```

And you will have the 4.

As they are "single" properties, that will do the trick.

**EDIT**

oh, as `ItineraryDays` in Itinerary (could have guess, by the way) seems to be a collection , think you have to do

```
.Include(i => i.ItineraryDays.Select(id => id.Listing.Port.Country))
```

Comment: Hi, When I try this intellisense informs me that: cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. Any ideas why? cheers, Guy

Comment: @GuyNorton Kk, see Edit, maybe ?

Comment: I had arrived at this: .Include(i => i.ItineraryDays.Select(l => l.Listing).Select(p => p.Port).Select(c => c.Country)) , but yours is better of course!